# Data for Invisible Columns When Using Horizontal Bar Is Not Displayed

Tags: ajax, json, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am working on jqxgrid (Dynamic Column). Here is part of my code:

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({ 
    width: 566,
    source: dataAdapter,
    autoheight: true,
    columnsresize: true,
    sortable: false,
    columns: columns
});
```

They sit in the success handler of the Ajax request. My code will make ajax request every 3 seconds, take the data in json format, and build the jqxgrid. That means it will keep re-generating the grid. However I am having strange situation. In first iteration, the data is displayed as expected. But for the next iteration, the data will be shown on the visible columns only. I have lots of columns, so the horizontal bar is there.

The current visible column will show the data but not the invisible one. However if I scroll to the right, on the next iteration the data is displayed and the other invisible column will not have the data. I confirmed that I received all the data. And another interesting part is only the column which has the number is having the problem. The column which has characters is good. I try to change the datafield to string, int, also number but seems no luck as yet. I took days just to figure out this strange behavior.

Hopefully somebody could help me. Thank you.

Comment: could you post more code or a minimal jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: I have posted question on jQWidget forum. See this http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/data-for-invisible-columns-when-using-horizontal-bar-is-not-displayed/ I still don't know what is the main reason. I guess it is because of the process of re-drawing the grid. I solved it using some little trick as posted in the forum.